# EFI partition vs /boot partition

Tags: boot, partition, uefi, boot-loader

I am having trouble understanding the difference between the **EFI System Partition (ESP)** and the linux **/boot partition**.

Reading online tells me that `/boot` partition is going to contain the boot loader i.e. GRUB2. Then, if that's the case, and if I store GRUB on the ESP, then is it same as the `/boot` partition ?

Or is it that GRUB2 is suppose to be stored on the ESP (something I have done before, and it worked) and the `/boot` partition is suppose to contain files for GRUB to find, typically files needed to be loaded before, let's say, an encrypted LVM is loaded.

What are the difference between these two ?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @direprobs Ubuntu

Comment: You might be interested in [Rod's books](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html) on EFI, I keep recommending those as someone whom these helped a **lot** during UEFI implementation in [ALT Linux](https://en.altlinux.org/rescue). :)

Answer (score 9):

The EFI System Partition is the partition the EFI firmware (in ROM on the motherboard) knows of and from which the firmware can load EFI applications like boot loaders. So the ESP is the place where you put GRUB2 for the firmware to load and run. The `/boot` directory/partition is the place for GRUB to find files it needs, like you said. However, there is no reason the ESP and `/boot` can't be the same partition.

Comment: Unless you are running Debian, which has a policy that `/boot` cannot be a FAT32 file system (which the ESP must be), because FAT32 does not support symlinks.

Comment: For example on my system running Ubuntu, `/boot` is a directory, whereas, the ESP partition is of type fat32 and mounted on `/boot/efi`.

Comment: If you wan't to do without GRUB and have the firmware boot the kernel directly, the ESP and `/boot` must be the same partition, or at least the kernel image must be put on the ESP.

Comment: That's interesting, I thought the firmware is only capable of executing .efi files. I'll try that for sure to see what happens. Part of the problem, my EFI firmware doesn't provide a menu.

Comment: It requires the kernel to be configured with `CONFIG_EFI_STUB`, which makes the kernel file an EFI binary.

Comment: Additionally, if you're multibooting with something other than Linux, it is often safer to have the ESP be a separate partition from `/boot` because it reduces the chances that the other OS will mess things up in `/boot`.

Comment: @JohanMyréen So lets say I wanted to run grub-mkconfig, I would have to be on the `/boot` partition for the command to work right ?

Comment: @ng.newbie Not to my knowledge. grub-mkconfig knows where to read its input and the examples show that you can write the output anywhere you want: `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Though I'm no GRUB expert, I made my life simpler by leaving GRUB behind. :)

Comment: @JohanMyréen Really what do you use ? What would you use if your system was encrypted ?

Comment: @JohanMyréen Could please link some information on how to dual boot without grub ?

Comment: @ng.newbie I use [systemd-boot](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/systemd-boot/) together with an efistub kernel on UEFI. Here is also the Arch Linux wiki page on [systemd-boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot). Configuration is done using simple 4-5 line text files. Installing several OSes requires a little planning how to put things in separate subdirs. I don't use an encrypted file system, so can't help you there. I do know the ESP can't be encypted.

Comment: @JohanMyréen i wasn't referring to the ESP being encrypted. I was talking about the /root and /home partitions. Is dual booting possible with systemd-boot ?

Comment: Systemd-boot follows the [BootLoaderSpec](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/BootLoaderSpec/) which deals with dual (and triple, ...) booting. Apparently, not many distros have adopted the spec yet, so "some assembly may be required".